# I need somebody to explain me why $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus

I need somebody to explain me why

$$\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$$

I don't get it. I'd say the left hand side is 0, because there is no change in $y^2$ when x changes slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the answer depends on what $y$ is.  If $y$ is just a free variable, then you're right and the derivative is $0$.  But if $y$ is a function of $x$ (i.e., $y=y(x)$) then the identity you wrote is an example of the chain rule in action.

Comment: The identity that Andrew wrote is correct either way - but if $y$ is a free variable, then ${dy\over dx}$ is $0$ and so of course $2y{dy\over dx}$ is identically $0$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki True, but $2y\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a pretty verbose way to write $0$. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are considering that $y$ is some function of $x$.  An example would be if $y=x^3$.  Then $y^2=x^6, \frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=2y\frac{dy}{dx}=2x^3(3x^2)=6x^5=\frac{d}{dx}x^6$.  This is an example of the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) in action.

Comment: One question, how you went from $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2) \ to \ 2y\frac{dy}{dx}$, I can understand $y^2=2y$ but where does that $\frac{dy}{dx}$(next to 2y) come from?

Comment: @Andrew: $y^2 \neq 2y$... but the $dy/dx$ comes from the chain rule. Since we are looking for $\frac{d}{dx}y(x)$ we need to use the chain rule, that is, $\frac{d}{dx}y(x) = y'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$. I think the difficulty comes in when you're composing $y(x)$ with other functions.

Comment: OK, I got it totally. I'll tell you what was the difficulty. I am used to having the chain rule as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ here, the y was used as the variable. I changed it to u and still kept the dy/dx as in the original form and everything is clear now. :) Thank you a lot.