# Why is $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+y^2)=2x+2y(y')$ but $\frac{d}{dy}(x^2+y^2)$ is only $2y$?

Tags: calculus

I was reviewing implicit differentiation for DVQ and spent some time understanding why:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+y^2)$=$2x+2y(y')$

and I felt like I got it. Then today $\frac{d}{dy}$$(x^2+y^2)$ came up in a problem and I thought, "Great, that must be $2y+2x(x')$. But it is somehow just $2y$. What is the difference?

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$, while $x$ does not depend on $y$? (That is, $\frac{d}{dy} x = 0$.)

Comment: The expression is correct. Somewhere in the context, $x'$ must be $0$.

Comment: Clement C., in the second instance x is a function of y, hence the dy in the denominator, right? So won't $\frac{d}{dy}$x not equal zero?

Comment: And GoodDeeds, there were other components to the problem but I typed the equation just as I did up there ^ into wolframalpha twice, only changing the ind. variable in the denominator, and I got the same discrepancy that is causing me confusion.

Comment: I have the feeling that what you've seen might have been $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2 + y^2)$ instead of $\frac{d}{d y}(x^2 + y^2)$.

Comment: Actually yes it was but I didn't know that made a difference! Could you please explain?

Comment: That's the notation for the partial derivative with respect to $y$. You differentiate with respect to $y$ keeping all the other variables constant.

Comment: The symbol $\partial$ is used in situations where functions might depend on several variables, in our case both $x$ and $y$. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is the operation of differentiating a function $f(x,y)$ while keeping it's other parameter fixed. In case there's a further dependence of $y$ on $x$, write $y(x)$, the total derivative $\frac{df}{dx}$ means the 1-dimensional derivative $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y(x))$.

Comment: You should think about why those two notions are very different from each other (they also give very different results) and are used in different contexts. It takes some time to internalize, so beware whenever you see the $\partial$ symbol until it's second nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some very helpful responses that I am going to summarize as an official answer. Thanks to mm8511 and Georg Lehner for the clear answers and GoodDeeds and Clement C. for the helpful comments.

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+y^2)=2x+2y(y')$ is solved with implicit differentiation. The problem is asking for differentiation in terms of $x$. For $x^2$ this is simply $2x$ but for $y^2$ the chain rule must be used since it is not already in terms of x. With the chain rule you will find $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}(y^2)$ which is $2y(y')$.

Now if your repeated the last problem with the independent variable as $y$, $\frac{d}{dy}$, you would repeat the above to arrive at  $\frac{d}{dy}(x^2+y^2)=2x(x')+2y$.

If you tried to compute  $\frac{d}{dy}(x^2+y^2)$ but $x$ was not a function of $y$ in any way, then you would end up with just $2y$, but this is a bit of a contradiction in notation and was not the source of my error.

My error was that partial derivatives were used. A partial derivative calls for, in summary, only one variable to be differentiated in an equation with more than one variable. The other variables are held constant. So the true is question why:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2+y^2)=2y$

and the answer is because we are only differentiating the $y$ variable while the $x$ is being held constant.

Answer (score 0):

[I need somebody to explain me why $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82019/i-need-somebody-to-explain-me-why-fracddxy2-2y-fracdydx?rq=1)

This explains your question. It is basically an application of the chain rule, since f=y(x).
(note, I do not have enough rep to comment, I apologize for posting this as an answer).

Comment: Right, in the first problem x is the indep. and y is the dep. So you can differentiate $x^2$ to $2x$ and for $y^2$ you need to use the chain rule to get $2y(y')$. But in the second problem y is the indep. and x is the dep. so wouldn't the result just be switched?

Comment: I see what you're saying... If y is a function of x, then you are correct. you would have the same answer as the first problem with x and y interchanged. However, if y is a function of x, then $(d/dy(y^{2}+x^{2})=2y))$... This website might be helpful for you https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html

Comment: Also, KhanAcademy.com is another great resource. He has plenty of videos on implicit differentiation with examples and other related topics. Hope that helps.